# Thunderbird Address Book - Merging Duplicates

Tags: thunderbird, address-book

I have an address book in Thunderbird that has a ton of duplicates.  I reied using the add on at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/53145/ but that ended up losing data during the migration.

I can export the address book to a .MAB file.  Does anyone know of an app I can use to edit the MAB?  Be great if I could get it into excel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I exported to CSV and used Excel to manually merge the duplicates.

That wasn't as time consuming as I thought, but it was manual.

And a couple of caveats:

- Screenname was not exported
- Anniversary Date and Spouse were not exported
- During import, Anniversary date, spouse, and categories were not imported.